# Checking how many members is there in a class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ macro/metaprogram to determine number of members at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844605/c-macro-metaprogram-to-determine-number-of-members-at-compile-time)

is there a way to detect at compile time how many members class has?
I've looked the web but no results.

Comment: What do you propose to do with the information?

Comment: Code browsers like Eclipse-CDT provides you this information without compilation !

Comment: here is a link for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844605/c-macro-metaprogram-to-determine-number-of-members-at-compile-time

Answer (score 0):

There are API's for static analysis tools that could do this.
Here at my work I use a product called understand 4 C++. It has a nifty C API, for which I wrote a managed [C++/CLI wrapper API](http://understandapi.codeplex.com/). That allows you to write tools using C# to target their API. Using this I have written tools that do things similar to what you want to do.

In your case, you could write a tool, get it to do what you want, and then call this tool as a post build event.

If you search this website for static analysis API's then you will find other useful hits.