# How do I determine the number of parameters of a std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, template-meta-programming, generic-programming

I have the following problem. Say you want to write a generic function that can take a lambda expression. I understand that if the parameter is of type std::function, then I could not only use lambdas, but also functions and even pointers to functions. So at a first step, I did the following:

```
void print(std::function<void(int, int)> fn) {
  fn(1,2);
}

int main() {

  print([](int i, int j) { std::cout << j <<','<<i<<'\n'; });
  return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to make this function generic, meaning that I don't want the lambda expression to have only two parameters.
So I tried changing the signature of the print function to something more generic like:

```
template <class function_type>
void print(function_type fn);
```

But now the problem is that the function takes ANY object and I'm not ok with that.
But the main problem is that, I have no idea how many parameters the object fn can accept.

So in a way I'm looking for a compile time way to determine how many arguments fn has, and if possible to change the type of fn to std::function. And then, given that I know the number of parameters that fn accepts, is there a generic way to pack an arbitrary number of parameters to be passed to fn? I don't even know if this is possible within C++11. What I mean is that given the number of arguments, is there a way to pack parameters to pass to fn? So that if there are two arguments, then I would call

```
fn(arg1, arg2);
```

if there are three:

```
fn(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

and so on.

Thank you all for your insight.

aa

Comment: How do you expect to implement this for different function aritys?

Comment: What values are you going to pass for the parameters?

Comment: I'll pass only integral types, and all the same. But the class is templated by the number of parameters.

Comment: What class is templated? There's no class in your question.

Comment: Because I simplified the code to explain the problem. What I have is an object that can be constructed by passing a functor, or a lambda expression. For example this object is templated by a dimension, so if it's 1D then I would have to call the functor with only one parameter, if it's 2D with 2 parameters and so on...

Answer (score 2):

The following snippets might be useful.

This gives the number of arguments that a `std::function` takes

```
template <typename Signature>
struct count_args;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct count_args<std::function<Ret(Args...)>> {
    static constexpr size_t value = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

For example the following code compiles (clang 3.2, gcc 4.7.2 and icc 13.1.0)

```
static_assert(count_args<std::function<void()        >>::value == 0, "Ops!");
static_assert(count_args<std::function<void(int)     >>::value == 1, "Ops!");
static_assert(count_args<std::function<void(int, int)>>::value == 2, "Ops!");
```

As far as I understand, you want to call the function object passing the correct number of arguments, right? Then for each argument we need to provide a value which is convertible to its type. A solution with this generality is very hard (or even impossible). Hence, I'll present two alternatives.

**1** Each argument is a value initialized object of its type. (This is what [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807558/1137388).)

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
Ret call(const std::function<Ret(Args...)>& f) {
    return f(Args{}...); // for the intel compiler replace {} with ()
}
```

**2** A fixed value is given and all the arguments are implicitly initialized from this value:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args, typename Val, typename... Vals>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == sizeof...(Vals), Ret>::type
call(const std::function<Ret(Args...)>& f, const Val&, const Vals&... vals) {
    return f(vals...);
}

template <typename Ret, typename... Args, typename Val, typename... Vals>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > sizeof...(Vals)), Ret>::type
call(const std::function<Ret(Args...)>& f, const Val& val, const Vals&... vals) {
    return call(f, val, val, vals...);
}
```

The three overloads are unambiguous and can be used as the following examples show:

```
{
    std::function<char()> f = []() -> char {
        std::cout << "f() ";
        return 'A';
    };
    std::cout << call(f)    << std::endl; // calls f()
    std::cout << call(f, 0) << std::endl; // calls f()
}
{
    std::function<char(int)> f = [](int i) -> char {
        std::cout << "f(" << i << ") ";
        return 'B';
    };
    std::cout << call(f)    << std::endl; // calls f(0)
    std::cout << call(f, 1) << std::endl; // calls f(1)
}
{
    std::function<char(int, int)> f = [](int i, int j) -> char {
        std::cout << "f(" << i << "," << j << ") ";
        return 'C';
    };
    std::cout << call(f)    << std::endl; // calls f(0, 0)
    std::cout << call(f, 2) << std::endl; // calls f(2, 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pack as many parameters to `fn` as you wish using variadic templates.

```
template <class function_type, class... Args>
void print(function_type fn, Args... args)
{
    //Call fn with args
    fn(std::forward<Args>(args...));
}
```

To find out how many args there are in the parameter pack, you can use `sizeof...(args)`.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your answer. The print function, however, takes a single argument (the functor or lambda expression). What I need is a way to determine with how many parameters I can call fn. Is this even possible?

For example, imagine that print is a member function of a class, and depending on the number of parameters that fn accepts, the class will call fn with that number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the signature of a callable, you can use the solution from [Inferring the call signature of a lambda or arbitrary callable for "make_function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893141/inferring-the-call-signature-of-a-lambda-or-arbitrary-callable-for-make-functio).  You can then package the callable into a `std::function`, or create a tag and use parameter inference:

```
template<typename T> struct tag {};

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void print_impl(F &&fn, tag<void(Args...)>) {
  fn(Args{}...);
}

template<typename F>
void print(F &&fn) {
  print_impl(std::forward<F>(fn), tag<get_signature<F>>{});
}
```

Note this uses value-initialised arguments; if you want anything more complex you can build a `std::tuple<Args...>` and pass that along, invoking it per ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer?lq=1).

Comment: Hi ecatmur, I'm having problems understanding that code. Given that I know the signature of the functor, I still need to know the number of parameters of that signature at compile time to trigger the right function call to the functor, correct? Or I'm missing something fundamental?

What I need is this: let's have an object that can be constructed by passing a functor, or a lambda expression. For example this object is templated by a dimension, so if it's 1D then I would have to call the functor with only one parameter, if it's 2D with 2 parameters and so on.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon no, the number of parameters can be inferred from the computed signature.